# How verify cancelled print job in script

Tags: shell-script, printing, cups, jobs, lp

I need to verify that a print job has been cancelled, and to do this in a script.

But lpstat's "completed-jobs" list appears to include those that have been cancelled. So it appears I cannot deduce that a job has been cancelled by it's not appearing in the completed list. And I can see no way of querying it.

How can I do this?

*The purpose of doing this, btw, is to record the datestamps of actually completed jobs, so that those jobs are not printed again unnecessarily when next determining which files to print. I.e. print only those files that have not already been successfully printed unless they have been since modified. It is necessary to know which of the "completed" jobs were not printed successfully.*

Comment: By reading `man lpq lpstat` you can use `lpq` to see it disappear from the queue. Also, the data file associated with a spooled request is (for print request 456) `/var/spool/cups/d00456-001` .

Comment: Thx waltinator. A job disappearing from the queue doesn't mean it's completed though. It might have been cancelled. Hence the question about handling cancelled jobs in a script.